# PageSpeed Insights API V6 Client Library for .NET Availability

Tags: c#, .net, pagespeed

`PageSpeed Insights API` Client Library V.6 for .NET is still unavailable. Is there an alternative or Beta Library for it?

*P.S:* I have checked various resources (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis, Google) and did not find an update or Release pointing to PageSpeed V6 API.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we are unable to predict when or if future events may occur.

Comment: @Ryan, we investigated and found that PageApeed API calls made when .NET Client for Pagespeed Insight gets called is already on Version 6. Hence, no need of a separate new version of client library. However, the internal REST API call that is made to trigger Lighthouse scores is still saying v5 in its url though the results returned are V6 results. This confusion led us to find latest client library. Please unlock the question so that I could provide this research as an answer to my question.

Comment: That sounds reasonable: if it's already available, then it wouldn't be a prediction about the future. I have voted to reopen the question.

Comment: To clarify, no one is ever supposed to wait before voting to close a question. You are expected to provide all required information in the question from the beginning. If it's missing, we have [edit]s and the ability to reopen as an escape mechanism, but it's merely that: an escape mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

We investigated and found that PageApeed API calls made when .NET Client for Pagespeed Insight makes a call is already on Version 6. Hence, no need of a separate new version of client library. However, the internal REST API call that is made to trigger Lighthouse scores is still saying v5 in its URL though the results returned are V6 results. This confusion led us to find the latest client library.